# How to achieve a fixed scroll value with RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, rxjs

I have a block with a mat-table inside. It has a scroll, initially the initial value of this scroll is 0. I need the value to be 2 or more. If you scroll to a height of 0, what would change again to 2 automatically. the same with the final value of the scroll. If you scrolled 1000, then after scrolling to 1000 it changed to 998.

file TS

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

  public dataSource: Post[] = [];
  public displayedColumns: string [] = ['id', 'title', 'body'];

  @ViewChild('content', {static: true}) content: ElementRef;

  constructor(private service: DataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllPosts()

    fromEvent(this.content.nativeElement, 'scroll').pipe(
      map((event: Event) => (event.target as Element).scrollTop)).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  }

  getAllPosts() {
    this.service.getData().pipe().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = data
    })
  }

}
```

file html

```
<div #content class="mat-elevation-z8 content">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" >
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="body">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Body</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.body}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What is the issue?

I can see a problem in the code, and is the lifecycle ngOnInit

Be careful

When you are using a viewChild like:

```
  @ViewChild('content', {static: true}) content: ElementRef;
```

On the ngOnInit, this.content has not been initialized yet

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllPosts()
     //this.content.nativeElement doesn't exist
    fromEvent(this.content.nativeElement, 'scroll').pipe(
      map((event: Event) => (event.target as Element).scrollTop)).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  }
```

So, I recommend you to change the logic, from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot implement that the scroll would have a fixed start not 0 but 2 or more. As soon as I would scroll to 0 it would become 2 again.